# Can't modify style css for link

Tags: css

I am trying to override the classic blue colour of my links in my CSS file, but none of the options found on the web seem to work for me. I've also checked my cache so it's not that the changes don't appear. I'm checking in IE, Firefox and Chrome.

I tried:

```
a:link { color:red };
```

AND just in case:

```
a:link { color:red; }
```

OR:

```
a {
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

No impact whatsoever.

Comment: Post a jsfiddle which demonstrates the issue because the first thing you posted works perfectly fine.

Comment: Whats the issue? http://jsfiddle.net/nguk1jvd/1/

Comment: Probably there's something you can't overwrite. So we need to view your code (html). One thing possible is to add !important to your attribute: a,a:link {color:red !important;} But it's better don't use it if you can overwrite in other way.

Comment: You need to edit your original question to add the HTML code. Comments are not intended for that.

Comment: Hi @keypaul, thanks for trying to help. Here's my terrible attempt: https://jsfiddle.net/laurage/ehoav3oz/
As you can see I've also tried to add it in the html itself, but no more result.

Comment: there're a lot of error in css code, just that: https://jsfiddle.net/keypaul/ehoav3oz/4/

Comment: I fixed errors as i supposed the should be.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help!
One major thing seems to be that my <a> link was placed in the <body>. Is that not possible? (newbie: I'm learning!). Cheers!

Comment: The body contains everything in the HTML part; about CSS part it's a different question, there you litterally "describe" how the different elements should appear. So, basically, you build the structure and the "nesting stuffs" in the HTML, than "describe" attributes in CSS. The "nesting" of the HTML don't have to be reproduced in the CSS

Comment: If you are starting with html/css i suggest to read those two  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Learn/CSS + https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Learn/HTML . Good study.

Answer (score 2):

I'd add a:

```
a:visited { color: red };
```

I am supposing you'd visited that links before; in that case empting cache has no effect....
Anyway difficoult to guess without the code.

Ok i fixed your Fiddle to make it work
https://jsfiddle.net/ehoav3oz/6/

There were severals sintax errors; fixed both CSS and HTML